# css background position animation infinity

Tags: css, animation

How to add a progressbar-like animation on a button?

When the `loading` class is added to the button the background position should move to the right in an infinite loop.. Like a progress bar loading

The problem here is that the position move in different tempo

## code

```
<button class="loading">Loooong text on button</button><br><br>
<button class="loading">Short</button>

@keyframes animation_loading {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 25px 0; }
}

button.loading {
    background-image:url(//www.dynaccount.com/tmp.png);
    animation:animation_loading 0.5s linear infinite;
}
```

## fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/KP2W4/

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle. You can also use the progress element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a keyframe animation which moves the background image on the x-axis like this:

```
@keyframes loading{
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: -100% 0;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tryzor/8urz5/1/)

Comment: You should try adding general properties and than use proprietary tags, cuz your answer is correct but the fiddle fails in firefox, fix and I'll upvote you :)

Comment: have updated my quesion.. the problem here is that the tempo is different on elements with different width

Comment: found a solution.. thanks.. just put the image width instead of 100%